# How do I uninstall Pandoc in Ubuntu 19.10 (and install most recent version)

Tags: 19.10, pandoc

I have an old version of Pandoc installed, but I'd like to install the latest version of Pandoc.

To begin I've run the following to get rid of the old version: 
`sudo apt-get autoremove --purge pandoc`

But when I check that everything is uninstalled by running:
`pandoc --version`
Then `pandoc 2.2.3.2` pops up.

I can't seem to get rid of this old version of pandoc so that I can install a new one.

Could you advise me on how I can get rid of the old version and install the new one please.

Comment: What is the output of `which pandoc` and `dpkg -l | grep pandoc`?

Comment: `which pandoc` gives `/anaconda3/bin/pandoc` . `dpkg -l | grep pandoc` doesn't give an output.

Comment: So the anaconda causes this problem. You have to decide yourself - remove it from PATH environment variable or not.

Comment: thanks. so might it make sense to update anaconda?

Comment: I do not know your exact use case. We have discovered the problem, now you can solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing is possible by

```
sudo apt-get purge pandoc pandoc-citeproc pandoc-data
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

Installation is usually as simple as visiting [Pandoc site](https://pandoc.org/installing.html) and download the [latest version](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/latest) of deb-file as the result:

```
wget https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/download/2.9.2.1/pandoc-2.9.2.1-1-amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./pandoc-2.9.2.1-1-amd64.deb
```