# Installing Pandoc with dpkg instead of apt

Tags: apt, dpkg, pandoc

Since the apt pandoc is still version 1.19 I thought I would try to install it from here https://packages.debian.org/buster/amd64/pandoc/download. But something went wrong:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i /tmp/mozilla_felix0/pandoc_2.2.1-3+b2_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package pandoc.
(Reading database ... 197422 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../pandoc_2.2.1-3+b2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pandoc (2.2.1-3+b2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pandoc:
pandoc depends on pandoc-data (>= 2.2.1-3); however:
  Version of pandoc-data on system is 1.19.2.4~dfsg-1build4.

dpkg: error processing package pandoc (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 pandoc
```

whenever I use pandoc I get this error message now

```
Could not find data file /usr/share/pandoc/data/abbreviations
```

I am not sure what I should do now. It is my first time using dpkg. I guess I need to purge the old version somehow, but I already used `apt remove pandoc` before, so I am unsure what went wrong.

Comment: I installed the previous version using apt

Comment: Looks like you are running 18.04, and have the classic question [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software). Ubuntu 20.04 has pandoc 2.5. Newer software = Newer release of Ubuntu.

Comment: The specific problem you are encountering is NOT due to an old version on the system. It's because the NEW version requires a whole cascade of dependencies...and the new package you downloaded is incompatible with at least one of those older dependencies. This kind of incompatibility is known as a *version conflict* . The easy way to fix it it to install all your packages from a single source (like Ubuntu 18.04 or Ubuntu 20.04). DON'T mix packages from different releases - that's what causes version conflicts. Yes, it's very different from how Windows or Mac works. Embrace the difference.

Comment: You are right I am on 18.04 but I haven't gotten a prompt for an update of ubuntu - does that mean you have to regularly check whether updates for the operating system are available yourself? I thought I got some software updates from time to time

Comment: The upgrade from 18.04.x to 20.04.1 will be offered in July 2020.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I uninstall Pandoc in Ubuntu 19.10 (and install most recent version)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239932/how-do-i-uninstall-pandoc-in-ubuntu-19-10-and-install-most-recent-version) - use official pandoc package, do not mix the Debian and Ubuntu packages!

Comment: I think my question was answered by "The specific problem you are encountering is NOT due to an old version on the system... " apparently I did correctly deinstall it, but dependencies in the operating system itself aren't there I guess.